# Bad output after split and map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I run following code and javascript return crazy resualt?

code:

`"000000000000000000000000".split('').map(parseInt)`

output:

`[0, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

why second item of array is NaN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` [actually takes two arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the second one being the radix; `map` will [provide three arguments to the called function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): the current value, the current index, and the whole array.

This means that the first item will be `parsetInt(0, 0)`, the second one `parseInt(0, 1)` and so on...

You should force the arguments count:

```
"000000000000000000000000".split('').map(function(n) { return parseInt(n); })
```

Comment: Or you can use `.map(Number)`.

Comment: And `parseInt('0', 1)` is a NaN because... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371972

Answer (score 2):

> map calls the function with three parameters. The first is the
>   element, the second is the index in the array (the third is the array
>   itself). parseInt takes two arguments.

It's cleary explained here:

http://www.quora.com/Exactly-why-does-10-10-10-10-10-map-parseInt-return-10-NaN-2-3-4-in-JavaScript